# How do I minimize the sum of the distances between two points and a line?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose we have a line $y=mx$ for some $m \in \mathbb{R}$, and two points $A(a_1,a_2)$ and $B(b_1,b_2)$ somewhere in the 2-dimensional Euclidean space. Where should I place a point $C(c_1,c_2)$ along $y=mx$ to minimize $AC+BC$?

My first instinct was to create a function $L(c_1) = AC+BC$, take the derivative, set it to zero, etc. However (after replacing $c_2$ with $mc_1$ of course), This is the expression I get for the derivative:
$L'(c_1) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ (m^2+1)c_1^2-2(a_1+ma_2)c_1+a_1^2+a_2^2 \right]^{-\frac{1}{2}} \left[ (m^2+1)c_1 -(a_1+ma_2) \right] + \frac{1}{2} \left[ (m^2+1)c_1^2-2(b_1+mb_2)c_1+b_1^2+b_2^2 \right]^{-\frac{1}{2}} \left[ (m^2+1)c_1 -(b_1+mb_2) \right]$

Which, needless to say, is a function I do not know how to set equal to zero.

Comment: Create two separate functions $y_1$ and $y_2$ of the distance between the line and points. Find the minimum of both individual functions and this will be the minimum value of $AC+BC$.

Comment: If using calculus is not mandatory, you can simply reflect point $A$ across given line and choose $C$ such that $B, C, A'$ are collinear.

Comment: A problem with the the analytic approach above is that the optimality conditions are hard to connect with the geometry.

Comment: The geometry is that the angles of approach to the line are the same at the optimum. The involvement of angles with the extrema is a common theme with sum of distances minimisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If calculus is not mandatory,

Reflection of a point $(x_1, y_1)$ (not residing on the line) against line $y = mx + c$ is given by,

$\displaystyle \small y - y_1 = \frac{x-x_1}{-m} = \frac{-2(y_1-mx_1-c)}{1+m^2}$

So in this case, $A'(x,y)$ coordinates will be,

$\displaystyle \small x = a_1 + \frac{2m(a_2-ma_1)}{1+m^2} = \frac{(1-m^2) a_1 + 2ma_2}{1+m^2}$

$\displaystyle \small y = a_2 - \frac{2(a_2-ma_1)}{1+m^2} = \frac{2m a_1 - a_2 (1-m^2)}{1+m^2}$

Now note that $AC = A'C$ as $A'$ is reflection of point $A$ against the line that $C$ resides on.

$AC + BC = A'C + CB \ $ is min when $A'CB$ is a straight line. So equating the slopes,

$\displaystyle \small \frac{y - b_2}{x-b_1} = \frac{mc_1 - b_2}{c_1 - b_1}$

Solving this, you get the value of $c_1$ and then the coordinates of point $C$ that minimizes $AC + BC$ is $(c_1, mc_1)$.

Comment: Wow! Very helpful! Do you have any justification as to why "$AC+BC = A'C+CB$ is min when $A'CB$ is a straight line"?

Comment: Yes if you draw a triangle $\triangle A'CB$, $A'C + CB \gt A'B$, right? So if point $C$ is on line segment $A'B$, $A'C + CB = A'B$ otherwise $A'C + CB \gt A'B$ .

Comment: Right! Triangle inequality! I don't know how I forgot that. Thank you!